# Visual Studio 2022 Standalone react project files are hidden or dotted in solutions explorer

Tags: c#, reactjs, npm

I created a Visual Studio 2022 Standalone react project, after creation files and folders are hidden or dotted under npm.

I can not run project.

Comment: can you confirm with this [https://www.hanselman.com/blog/]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.